# Microsoft Edge Forces Margins when Printing CSS

Tags: css, printing, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge is forcibly adding margins to pages when attempting to print. None of the other browsers do this because I specified on my print.css file that I don't want margins like so:

@page { margin: 0; }

Microsoft Edge is the only browser that adds margins despite my css rule. Even when adding margin: 0 to the developer tools, I can see that rule disappear as soon as I click on Print.

From my research, this seems to be the default behavior for Edge.

Does anybody know a work around to this at least? I need all the horizontal real estate available for my page that I'm trying to print. I prefer not to have to do a redesign of the page just to accommodate Edge.

Comment: Any chance that you can provide me with a repro of what you're hitting and which version of Edge you're testing, because with this simple version http://jsbin.com/cebumeyaso/1/edit?html,css,output I get the following result in EdgeHTML 16: https://imgur.com/a/SCjgK

Comment: @gregwhitworth I have just come across this issue myself, the issue show's itself when you try to print to an actual printer, for me I am trying to print to a label writer (tiny pages, Edge margins take up about 70% of the page). when printing to PDF, you can print all the way to the edge, but not with a real printer.